# Calc adds ' (apostrophe) when importing time from CSV

Tags: csv, timestamps, libreoffice

I have a CSV file as shown below that contains time durations.
When I import into Calc, it looks good.

However, when I want to work with the time duration and manipulate them, it doesn't work. 
When I try to convert the duration into the following Time format : HH:MM:SS
It seems that it converts my data and adds an extra apostrophe in front of it.

is that a bug ? is there a way to fix that ?

[image]

Comment: How exactly are you importing the file? it sounds like the column is being identified as text - you may need to identify it explicitly as a datetime. See [Text import - Detect special numbers](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Text_Import#Detect_special_numbers)

Comment: I am importing the columns as "Standard". From the documentation in your link, it seems that LibreOffice determines the type during import

Comment: Next time please put the CSV contents in plain text rather than a screen capture.  I had to retype the data from the image.

Comment: Sure, I'll provide the raw data next time, sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import the data as strings, then convert into time values with this formula:

```
=TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(H2,8))
```

[TIMEVALUE](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/TIMEVALUE) returns a floating point number, which is the underlying value for dates and times.  To view it as a time, go to `Format -> Cells` or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>.

[image: set cell to use a time format]

The [RIGHT](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Text_Functions#RIGHT) function strips off the `Fri` part of the string, because these are times, not dates.

Adapted from kumiponi's answer at: https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/30713/please-find-me-easy-way-convert-date-string-into-data/

Answer (score 2):

The same problem was solved [here](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/87210/calc-conversion-text-to-date/). I have test it - it work.

I copied gif file from there to here:

[image]

Explanation:

1. Select the column
2. Click Data>Text to columns
3. In the dialog, click the column
4. The "Column type" selector ungreys itself, select a date format

Comment: Thanks for this tip but it doesn't work in my case as I have durations (HH:MM:SS) and converting them into D/M/Y converts them from HH:MM:SS into a date (not what I want)

Comment: Have tried it just now - it work as expected. This trick needed for converting from text to nontext (removing apostrophe in the beginning of cell). Then you can adjust format by the standard way (selecting cells -> right mouse button -> 'Format cells' -> 'time' -> 'HH:MM:SS'.

Comment: Also, you can set needed format for cells firstly, then convert text to column. The converted text will be in the specified format, which you have choose at the beginning.

Comment: The solution brought by Jim K really works the best for me as I don't want to have to click on anything. A formula is always best !